# Find All in a Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I am working on an application to search for and build a list of all the times a string (or variable of) is in a text file. Kind of like a Find All function in a text editor that I can build a list with the info that is found, such as

S350
S250
S270
S5000

What can I use to do this search? It will have one value that does not change (The S in this case) followed by up to 4 digits

Comment: possible duplication of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286505/how-to-find-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

`RegEx` seems like a good choice.

Something like.. `S(\d{1,4})?` might work for you.

[Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) is my preferred regular expression composer.