# Counting specific text items in a listbox in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm a hobbyist trying to get to grips with some simple programming & chatbot learning, appreciate the help!

I'm trying to perform a count on a list box whereby a certain text exists at the beginning.

I.e. the below could be text in a listbox

You: Hi, how are you?
ChatBot: Hi, I am good thanks, how are you?
You: I'm ok I guess.
ChatBot: Why are you ok?
You: I just am.

*Note the "You:" and "ChatBot:" are both text included in the list box.

Is there a way I can perform a count (that is stored in a variable) on the list box so that I get a count for each time the word "ChatBot:" is read?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find the number of occurrences of a substring within a string vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286505/how-to-find-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood right this will work:

```
Dim chtb As Integer = 0
    For Each i As String In ListBox1.Items
        If i.StartsWith("ChatBot:") Then
            chtb += 1
        End If
    Next
```

`chtb` is how many times ChatBot responded

Comment: Looks weird seeing brackets on a property.. Might just be me. Nice answer though

Comment: Ooops. Sorry i fixed it :)

Comment: Thanks that you told me that it works. I couldn't test it. I wrote it from my phone :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
Dim i As Integer = (From item As String In ListBox1.Items Where item.StartsWith("ChatBot:")).Count
```